# `dpylr` count function for unique items in field

Tags: r

I have searched for this on here a few times, so apologies if this is a duplicate.

I am working with dplyr for the first time, and I am having trouble coming up with what I'd like.  If I was doing SQL, the query would look like:

```
select count(customer_id), sum(sales), (sum(sales) / count(customer_id), *
  from data_table
 group by salesperson_id
```

In words, I want to:

1. group the data by salesperson
2. add up the total sales
3. count the number of unique customers
4. find the average sales per customer for each sales person.

I don't want to strip away "irrelevant" fields at this point, because they will become relevant in later steps.

I am getting stuck, specifically because the only counting function `dplyr` provides doesn't take any arguments.  **What aggregate function should I use to count distinct items in a field?**

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some sample data?  For example, using `dput(head(df))` (where `df` is the name of the dataframe you are using)?

Answer (score 1):

Responding to the question: **What aggregate function should I use to count distinct items in a field?**

`n_distinct()`

See docs [here](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/n_distinct.html).

A broader example, though a [reprex](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex) in the original question would help:

```
data_table %>%
    group_by(salesperson_id) %>%
    mutate(
        customers = n_distinct(customer_id),
        sales = sum(sales),
        sales_per_customer = sales / customers
    )
```